# How to specify keyboard shortcuts for navigating through a List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts

I understand that `.keyboardShortcut` allows to add keyboard shortcuts to controls in SwiftUI. This is straightforward for a control with an obvious single primary action, such as a `Button`. But I would like to **add two shortcuts to a `List`, for navigating to the next and previous items**.

The purpose would be to allow the user to navigate the `List` without having to bring it into focus first (of course, when the `List` has focus, arrow keys can be used). For instance, using a `NavigationSplitView`, the user first navigates to the item they want to edit, then edit it, then they need to select the next item. In order to make selecting the next item more comfortable, I’d like the user to be able to use a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can add keyboard handling in the UIViewController that embeds your SwiftUI View (in UIHostingController) and pass relevant navigation command back to your SwiftUI view.

See https://useyourloaf.com/blog/adding-hardware-keyboard-shortcuts/ for adding keyboard handling to UIViewController.

Navigation logic (currently selected item and scrolling) should be handled in your SwiftUI view (or at the model that your SwiftUI view uses to display) data.

Answer (score -1):

My current solution is to add two dedicated `Button`s with their own shortcuts. This has the benefit of making explicit to the user that they can navigate using controls outside the `List`. Drawbacks are:

- Cluttering the screen;
- Duplicating the `List`’s functionality in the functions called by the `Button`s;
- The list doesn’t scroll when selection moves past displayed items.